# Android Wear "Google" app only shows weather info

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, google, android-wear, sony-smartwatch

I have been using my Sony SWR50 smart watch for about a week now and all is working just fine, everything syncs up as you'd expect.

However when I use the "swipe up" gesture to bring up the Google app, it only ever shows weather info (local, work and current location). I then swipe left to see more options and hit "More from Google" and it never actually gives me anything else, just the same 3 weather items again.

In contrast, on my phone (OnePlus 2) the google app shows the weather and a whole bunch of other stuff such as news articles, youtube feeds, traffic warnings etc.

On the watch there doesn't seem to be any way to configure what is shown.

How can I add more interesting stuff to the watch's google app content?

Comment: I never get articles on my watch, but I do get things like "time to home" or "time to work". On an LG Watch running 6.0.1.

Comment: I did get an amazon delivery notification appear on the google app on the watch but I would really like to have the same list of items as appears on the phone.  The phone does have a lot more items and I am able to customise them to a decent extent..

Comment: Don't think that is supported yet on Android Wear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Now on Android Wear can not be customised. It will get all cards from the phone that are "compatible". Here is a list of compatible cards on Android Wear:

- Stocks
- Weather
- Reminders
- Sports
- Traffic
- Flights
- Boarding pass
- Shipping confirmation for packages
- Public transit info on nearby trains & buses
- Friends’ birthdays
- Public alerts
- Reminders to leave on time for upcoming appointments
- Hotel & restaurant reservations

For more details: https://support.google.com/androidwear/answer/6056898?hl=en

Comment: Thank you for that link.  I guess I will have to wait for future releases of the apps to enrich my experience :)  I do like the Google Now launcher (which I installed on my phone just now).  It does a much better job than the chaotic, disjointed OnePlus launcher that I've had unknowingly (and subconsciously) loathing for about 3 months now.  Thanks for the information.  I'll try to remember to update this thread in the coming months to reflect any new developments.  Cheers!